# What is the advantage of using jquery DataTables for large databases?

Tags: jquery, datatable

The jquery DataTables plugin website says,

"if you are working with seriously large databases, you might want to consider using the server-side options that DataTables provides"

If so, what is the point of using DataTables over ASP.NET tools such as Dynamic Data?
Please tell me why one will or should use jquery DataTables over ASP.NET built-in tools.
Also, can anyone explain with which tools or plugins stack overflow built its data tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also, u can load the table data through json which makes the html page render faster. another great feature of datatable is it supports client side searching, sorting. Pagination (client/server side) through ajax/html request.

Answer (score 0):

datatable exposes a lot of functionalities for server side processing that you might use along with ASP.NET built-in tools. Following are the examples:

1. Obtain server-side data
2. Add extra HTTP variables
3. Use HTTP POST
4. Automatic addition of IDs and classes to rows
5. Reading table data from objects
6. Show and hide details about a particular record
7. User selectable rows (multiple rows)
8. JSONP for a cross domain data source
9. jEditable integration with DataTables
10. Deferred loading of Ajax data
11. Pipelining data (reduce Ajax calls for paging)

You can refer to [this link](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html), for details and examples