# Sort Table on link_to click event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, Project and Category.

I list out all my Project records on my views/projects/new.html.erb like this:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <tr class="project <% project.categories.all.each do |cat| %><%= cat.name %> <% end %>">
     <td><a href='project/<%= project.id %>'><%= project.filename %></a></td>
 <td><%= project.author %>
 <td><% project.categories.all.each do |cat| %><%= cat.name %>, <% end %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

And have defined several link_to remote links like this:

```
<div class="filterBy">SORT BY:</div>
<div class="filterBy"><%= link_to "Category", :update => "projects", :url => { :action => "sortTable", :filter => "Category" }, :remote => true %></div>                                        
<div class="filterBy"><%= link_to "Author", :update => "projects", :url => { :action => "sortTable", :filter => "Author" }, :remote => true %></div>
<div class="filterBy"><%= link_to "Date", :update => "projects", :url => { :action => "sortTable", :filter => "Date" }, :remote => true %></div>
```

And in my projects_controller I have

```
def sortTable 
  @projects = Project.find(:all, :order => params[:filter])
end
```

When I click the links though, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I want it to update without refreshing the page as well. If need be, my routes.rb looks like

```
Docside::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects
  resources :categories
  #get "home/index"
  root :to => "projects#new"
  match 'project/new',:controller=>"projects",:action=>"create"
  match "project/:id", :controller => "projects", :action=>"download"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In ur code, u r sending a remote server request just to get sorted data. this will kill the server with a number of requests. Since the primary requirement of ur list page is sorting data without refreshing the page, u can use datatables for it. Sample page using datatables -

add to ur appliation.js

```
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
```

in users controller

```
def index
  @users = User.all #collect all the users
end
```

in ur list/index view

```
%table#users
   %thead
     %tr
       %th User Name
       %th User Age
   %tbody
   %tfoot

:javascript 
  var users_list = true;
  var users = #{@users.to_json};  #convert the object collection to json
```

in ur users.js.coffee file

```
if users_list?
  usersColumnDefs = [ { "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 0, 1 ] }, { "sClass": "user-name", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }, { "sClass": "user-age", "aTargets": [ 1 ] } ]

  data = $.map(users, (user) ->
    return [[ user.name, user.age ]]
  )

  $('#users').dataTable
    "bSort": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sDom": sDom
    "aaData": data
    "aoColumnDefs": usersColumnDefs
```

Also see
[What is the advantage of using jquery DataTables for large databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743974/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-jquery-datatables-for-large-databases/12744212#12744212)